# pass CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in shell script

Tags: bash, cmake, escaping, quoting

I'm having a tedious issue involving bash and cmake and quoting, obviously.
I need to compile a program multiple times, with different cmake flags. After a lot of guessing, I came up with the following structure in a bash script:

```
cmake_params[1]=-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-O2\ -DNDEBUG
cmake_params[2]=-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-march=native\ -O2\ -DNDEBUG
# ....

#compile with:

for i in {1..n}
do
    # .. prepare ..
    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake "${cmake_params[$i]}" ..
    make
done
```

Note that I escaped whitespaces in the cmake_params and that cmake is called with double quotes. However, in the end, I need to be able to extend the flags to something as bad as:

```
cmake_params[1]=-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="clang++"\
  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="clang"\
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-march=native\ -O3\ -DNDEBUG\
  -DCMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION=true\
  -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0069=NEW
```

But that won't work. I tried quotes around the CXX flags, I tried omitting the quotes around the compiler and I tried omitting the quotes at the actual cmake call, all without success. The error messages vary, with the most prominent one being:

```
The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

clang++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-march=native -O3 -DNDEBUG
-DCMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION=true -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0069=NEW

is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
```

So obviously, cmake misinterprets my command line. To be extra clear, I want to pass clang++ as `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and `-march=native -O3 -DNDEBUG` as `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Which bash script will do that and why - are there any resources on how quoting and parameter passing works? I literally tried one thing after the other to find something that works, but that was not even educated guesswork..

Comment: Did you have any luck with it?

Answer (score 1):

When you write (in bash):

```
cmake "${cmake_params[$i]}"
```

You are asking it to invoke the command-line utility `cmake`, passing that utility a single argument, which is the value of the indicated element of the `cmake_params` array. Like any other command-line utility, `cmake` does not attempt to reinterpret the arguments it receives; it assumes that you have arranged to pass it correct arguments. So when it receives a single argument which says:

```
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-march=native -O3 -DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION=true -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0069=NEW
```

it proceeds to set the value of its internal variable `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` (the id before the `=`) to value `clang -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-march=native -O3 -DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION=true -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0069=NEW`.

`cmake` subsequently attempts to find the compiler by searching the path for the filename `clang -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-march=native -O3 -DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION=true -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0069=NEW`. Obviously, it doesn't find that file.

If things did not work that way, it would be essentially impossible to use filename arguments where there were spaces in the filepaths.

If that doesn't matter to you, you can go with a very simple solution: invoke `cmake` like this:

```
cmake ${cmake_params[$i]}
```

That tells the shell to get the value of the indicated element of the array `cmake_params`, and then (because it is not quoted) it performs word-splitting and pathname expansion on the value, resulting in a list of arguments which are then passed individually to `cmake`.

In the examples you present, this should work fine. But it is fragile and even dangerous. First, because pathname expansion will be performed, so a `*` in the value might turn into a complete list of files in the current directory. Second, because word-splitting is done using the value of the variable `$IFS`, which might conceivably have been altered. Finally, note that the shell does *not* interpret quotes (including backslashes) or parameter expansions inside the expanded value so there is no way to mark some whitespace inside the value as being exempt from word-splitting. That means you won't be able to use filenames or filepaths with spaces in them.

In modern bash versions, you can achieve a more precise solution using namerefs. A nameref is a variable declared with the `-n` flag with the name of another variable. You cannot create an array of namerefs, but a nameref can refer to an array.

With that in mind, we can rewrite your initial idea:

```
# Each param set has its own array variable. There is no need to use
# integer suffixes; you could use more descriptive tags. Just make sure
# that there is no other variable whose name starts with the same prefix.
# Since we are creating arrays, we do *not* quote whitespace *unless*
# it is really part of a parameter value.
declare -a cmake_params_1=(-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-O2 -DNDEBUG)
declare -a cmake_params_2=(-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-march=native -O2 -DNDEBUG)
# ....

# Now we can loop through the various arrays of parameter lists: 

# ${!word*} expands to a list of existing variables whose names start with  word   
for name in "${!cmake_params_*}"; do
    # Create a nameref for the array whose name we got from the list
    declare -n array=$name
    # .. prepare ..
    mkdir build
    cd build
    # Here we can use "array" as though it were the variable named in the argument
    cmake "${array[@]}" ..
    make
done
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply and thank you for shedding some light on that topic! I tried both ways, however, I still can't get it to work. When I use the first idea `cmake ${cmake_params[$i]}`, CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS are not set correctly. I get the error `Parse error in command line argument: -DNDEBUG` - I think, that means that -DNDEBUG is passed directly to cmake and not as part of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS. It does not help to use quotes around CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, like `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-march=native -DNDEBUG -O3"`. If I use the nameref idea, the flags are not passed at all, according to output from ccmake ...

Comment: ... which is a bit strange, as the flags *are* there, when I use the echo command on them. My bash seems to be rather old, my version (4.2.26) does not know the -n flag for the declare command.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
CMAKE_OPTS="-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF"
CMAKE_DEFAULTS="-GNinja \
                -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
                \"-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-Wformat -Werror=format-security -DNDEBUG -Ofast -march=native -flto -mtune=native\" \
                -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${INSTALL_PREFIX} \
                -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${INSTALL_PREFIX} \
"

curl -L -o source.tar.gz ${SRC_URL}
tar -xzf source.tar.gz

rm -rf build_ && mkdir build_ && cd build_
eval "cmake ${CMAKE_DEFAULTS} ${CMAKE_OPTS} ${SRC_PATH}"
cmake --build . --target install
```

Basically the thing is wrapping the whole `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` in `\"\"` and then calling `eval` (Impurity! I know I know...) on that.